# Execute single selenium test multiple times in parallel

Tags: selenium, parallel-processing, nunit

I was wondering if anyone had any advice of an easy way or executing a single selenium test multiple times in parallel.

I have 1 test that I would like to execute, it will then spin up 10 chrome instances and run the test 10 times in parallel, its an idea to test load/performance.

I could split the test up into individual classes and get them to run in parallel but this is a bit overkill, is there a simpler way of running this with Nunit?

Tests are written in c# and we are using NUnit at the test runner, we are using BDDfy for the test language.

Bit of a difficult question to write down but hope some people understand what I am trying to achieve

Comment: There's a few options available to you -- you mention C# and NUnit, so I think using the `Parallelizable` attribute from NUnit is one of the easiest approaches here.

Comment: I think you are using the wrong tool here. Selenium is not very good for performance testing. There are dedicated tools out there for this. This certainly doesn't answer your question. Before you go pounding a square peg (Selenium) into a round hole (performance testing) do some research about which performance testing solution would best fit your needs.

Comment: you'd just want to run each driver in it's own thread... one driver=one browser... but Greg is right, Selenium is going to be very bad at creating a significant amount of load.  If you still want to use it for some light load testing, I'd suggest using headless chrome, or HTMLUnit as the browser.  Much less overhead there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by adding multiple test cases on the same test, even if you don't have any parameters to pass to the test, and use `ParallelScope.All` on fixture to run all testcases within the fixture in parallel.

```
[TestFixture, Parallelizable(ParallelScope.All)]
public class MyTestFixture
{
    private static readonly IEnumerable<string> TestCases = new List<string>(new string[10]);

    [TestCaseSource(nameof(TestCases))]
    public void SingleTestRepeatedMultipleTimes(string testCase)
    {
        //test steps
    }
}
```